# Dynamically add a properties file in classpath in tomcat web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath

I am trying to add a properties file to the classpath dynamically as below

```
try {
    File fileToAdd = new File(FILE_PATH);
    URL u = fileToAdd.toURL();
    ClassLoader sysLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    if (sysLoader instanceof URLClassLoader) {
    sysLoader = (URLClassLoader) sysLoader;
    Class<URLClassLoader> sysLoaderClass = URLClassLoader.class;

    // use reflection to invoke the private addURL method
    Method method = sysLoaderClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL",
        new Class[] { URL.class });
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(sysLoader, new Object[] { u });
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

But i cant see this file in my classpath. When i checked it using

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

I cant see my file in this list. Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't add the URL of the properties file, you have to add the **URL of the directory** in which the properties file resides in. As in: `method.invoke(sysLoader, fileToAdd.getParent().toURL());`
then you can use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("my.properties");` and the ClassLoader will search the newly added directory for the file.

from [URLClassLoader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html)

*"This class loader is used to load classes and resources from a search path of URLs referring to both **JAR files and directories**. Any URL that ends with a '/' is assumed to refer to a directory. Otherwise, the URL is **assumed to refer to a JAR file** which will be opened as needed."*

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try this code, but changing java.library.path or keep it the way it is if you can live with using the library path instead.

```
    /**
     * Allows you to add a path to the library path during runtime
     * @param dllLocation The path you would like to add
     * @return True if the operation completed successfully, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean addDllLocationToPath(final String dllLocation)
    {
        //our return value
        boolean retVal = false;
        try
        {
            System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path") + ";" + dllLocation);
            //get the sys path field
            Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
            fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
            fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
            retVal = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Could not modify path");
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```